# Starting a server instance in separate thread is not passing server object to method

Tags: python, multithreading, stanford-nlp

I am trying to start Stanford NLP server in one separate thread and pass the server instance as a parameter to method `run_nlp` defined in class `Grid`, which is a layout class for my python application.

```
from readUseCase import parser
...
...
class Grid(Widget):
    text_from_file = ObjectProperty(None)
    client = ObjectProperty(None)

    def start_server(self):
        with CoreNLPClient(properties='./server.props') as self.client:
            pass

    def run_nlp(self):
        parser(self.client, self.text_from_file.text)

class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=Grid().start_server)
        thread1.start()
        return Grid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

So what happens is, I start app, `thread` starts, console prints out that the server is running, my app is also running and waiting for some user input. But when I input some text for NLP and I hit a button to start method `run_nlp()`, function `parser()` needs 2 input parameters, first is the server object and second is input text.

Function parser:

```
def parser(client, text):

    # submit the request to the server
    ann = client.annotate(text)      //AttributeError("NoneType" object has no attribute "annotate")
```

I am getting correct value in `self.text_from_file.text` parameter but I get `NoneType` for `self.client` parameter, and that is what I do not know why. I have tried to assign it to some other variable, or I tried to `return self.client` but none of this works.

Am I calling the `start_server` right? Or where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is because you create two objects of type `Grid` in the `build` method. One is used to start the thread but another one is created and returned. I think you should change your code to something like this:

```
class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        grid = Grid()
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=grid.start_server)
        thread1.start()
        return grid
```

Another problem could be, that client is at no point set. I don't know this library, but make sure you setup everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your context manager just starting and completing?  If the contents of the body are `pass` then the context manager will immediately finish and clean up the server.